# FineUploader div will not display class

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, fine-uploader

Here's a snippet of code into a :

```
<div id="manual-fine-uploader"></div>
<div id="triggerUpload" class="button" style="margin-top: 10px;">Save</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
         element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
         request: {
            endpoint: 'server/handleUploads'
         },
         autoUpload: false,
         text: {
            uploadButton: 'Select Files'
         }
      });

      $('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
         manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
      });
   });
</script>
```

As background, I'm using V3.5.0 of FineUploader, and I am using the standalone dependency free version.  I've literally just copied [this](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-demo.html) example for the FineUploader dev.  I changed the second div to say `class="button"` (a CSS style I use everywhere in my application).  However, no styling occurs.  Also where would I put a reference to one of my styles to custom style `uploadButton` in the javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! In the download package, came fineuploader-3-5-0.css. There you can change the button style. Even js or css has a "connection" to change this class, for example: qq-button (in css file).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Are you asking why the #triggerUpload button element is not styled the way you would expect it to be styled?

Comment: @RayNicholus I'm trying to get both the "Save" button and "Select Files" button styled.

Comment: @ViniciusLima Directly modifying the fineuploader.css does not yield any changes for me.  For example, I modified qq-upload-button (my "Save" button.  In fact the "Select Files" button never even appears.

Comment: @kmarks2, It's weird. I used to fineupload and I've changed css and my button showed in a diffent way. There is a relation between js and css. If you find in js, you'll find the classes related about css. I'm sorry to ask you, but do you import fileupload css file in your page? Again, sorry to ask this.

Comment: @ViniciusLima Webdev is not my main skill, but I thought my `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>` was importing the CSS.  Is there something else I need to do to import?  Also I rechecked that path, and VS is not giving me a "file not found" warning for it.

Comment: Sure! Set this code in <head></head> tag: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileuploader.css"  />. Your fileuploader.css must be in the same filepage level. Try this...

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you want to style the "save" button (which you have created) and the "select files" button (which Fine Uploader creates).

As far as the "Save" button is concerned, that is not related to Fine Uploader at all.  You have created this button, and it is not a part of Fine Uploader.  You can style it however you like via CSS.

Regarding the "Select files" button, you have three options:

1. Create your own div/anchor/etc element, and pass it to Fine Uploader via the [`button` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html#fineuploaderbasic-mode-options).  Fine Uploader will add an opaque file input element as a child of this button element.  Style your element however you like using CSS.
2. Create your own CSS (file), targeting the default button created by Fine Uploader's UI module.  There are numerous ways to ensure your CSS properties "win", but that is strictly a CSS question, and out of scope here really.
3. Override the `template` option.  I recommend not going this route.  Fine Uploader's template options are brittle and need to be improved in a later version.  You can read more about overriding the templates in the [first half of the styling readme](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/styling.html) but, again, I suggest you not do this.

Of the three options above, the first option is the easiest and the one I personally recommend.

It also sounds like you are simply not importing the CSS file that ships with Fine Uploader properly.  This is covered in the very first example "Setup" on the [demo page/website](http://fineuploader.com).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try these.  I'm confused why the fineuploader.com demos/code are simplified to the point of not working.  Seems like there is something missing.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to repeat the same import statements and boilerplate code in every example.  They are meant to be code snippets demonstrating specific features/concepts that assume you understand that any javascript/css files must be imported as well, and  a proper HTML document exists.  The first example: Setup, as I mentioned, includes these import statements as well.  If you have a valid HTML document, and you have imported whatever js/css files you use, the demos work just fine.